# Matlab standard deviation - treat vector as probabilities, not values

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

I have a vector in Matlab that looks something like:

```
vect = 0
     100
     300
     500
     700
    1000
     500
     300
     200
       0
```

When normalised, each value should indicate the probability of a certain value, and my values are just 1 to 10 (i.e. 0% chance of 1, `100/sum(vect)` chance of 2, etc).

How do I work out statistics on the value (in particular standard deviation)..?  If I do `mean(vect)`, I just end up with 360, and I get a similarly large value for standard deviation.  The mean value should, of course, be around 5.  I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard to code up manually at all, but there must be a way of doing this directly in Matlab, so I figured I'd ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure if matlab have any built in function for this, but it is no big deal. Both are one liners anyway

```
vect = [0; 100; 300; 500; 700; 1000; 500; 300; 200; 0];
prob = vect./sum(vect);
val = [1:10].';
meanVal = sum(prob.*val);
stDev = sqrt( sum( prob.*val.^2 ) -sum(prob.*val)^2 );
```

EDIT:

There are two functions that does this. They are called `mean` and `std` as well. But they take a probability distribution object instead.

Comment: yeah - this is definitely the way to do it explicitly, but it seems strange that there'd be no more direct route..

Comment: Well, I would say that in general you do not need a more direct way to do it. If you so dearly want to have a more direct way you should write a function of your own. Store it in a path that you always include in matlab or set it in a Place where you remember where it is like a "tools" folder or so and include it when you need it. However, look at `meanVal = sum(prob.*val)`. Can it really be a more, as you call it, direct route? It would probably be more work to first create a probability distribution object and possibly have more overhead and longer runtime as well.

Comment: @tiswas Also do you know that you can write a startup function as well in matlab. In that one you can add startup routines that is not already done by matlab. For example you can set a path in it. So if you have some tools that you Always want to include, you can add that to your startup function. So in other Words, if you think that matlab misses a oneliner you can take 5 minutes to write the function and set it in a path that is added in your startup function. You will never more need to care about it and you have only spent 5 mins of your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `stem(vect)` you'll see that `vect` is the probability density function of a normally distributed variable, hence you can fit a normal distribution to `vect` *without normalization*

```
x = (1:length(vect))';
pdf = fitdist(x, 'normal', 'freq', vect);
```

The result has an average value of 5.63889 and a standard deviation of 1.66944.